# Ajax jQuery error "google is not defined"?

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I have an ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard.phtml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(content){
  $(#div).html(content);
 }
  });
```

and my dashboard.phtml is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

 function drawChartPie1() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Open', openProjectsNum],
    ['Done', completedProjectsNum],
    ['Hold', onHoldProjectsNum]
  ]);

    var options = {
    'backgroundColor' : '#f8f8f8',
    'legend' : 'right',
    'title':'Project Status',
    'titleTextStyle':{
        color: 'dimgray', 
        fontSize: '14'
    },
    'colors':['#dc3912','#349853','#ea8706'],
    'chartArea.width':'auto',
    'chartArea.height':'auto',
    'height':'200',
    'width' : '260'
}

    var chart = new   google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div00'));
    chart.draw(data,options);
  }

var completedProjectsNum = 1;
var openProjectsNum = 2;
var onHoldProjectsNum = 3;
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie1);
</script>
```

But during ajax call i am getting the error "google is not defined"...Please help me to sort out this problem. Showing that error is in jquery-1.6.2.min.js. Due to this error the chart is not drawing. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the new `jQuery.ajax()` method. Next, try setting the `dataType` parameter to html.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "html"
}).done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
});
```